# PipelineDB: window functions

Tags: pipelinedb

Looking at the docs [Create continuous view](http://docs.pipelinedb.com/continuous-views.html#create-continuous-view) it's possible to create something like

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS VIEW cv AS
  SELECT
    ticketid,
    status,
    avg(status_duration) OVER w
  FROM stream
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY ticketid);
```

But I get the error

> ERROR:  continuous queries don't support WINDOW functions

Am I misunderstanding the docs? Can someone clarify how window functions can be used in continuous views?

Thanks

Comment: That's a bug in the docs, sorry about that. We'll update the docs shortly. Support for  window functions in continuous views was removed a few releases ago.

Comment: Is there some blog post about the reason that led to the removal of window functions in continuous views? Thanks.

Comment: There isn't a blog post, no. The reason they were removed is that internally they require special casing all throughout the core engine, and nobody was using them so those code paths weren't providing much benefit to anyone. It's possible that we'll introduce them again in the future if users generally want them.